# Arabic characters are displayed like ????? while called through jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have some issue with my web application as follows:

1) I am calling a controller though  Jquery ajax and getting response data in JSON format.

2) This controller hits data base and retrieve data from database, data retrieved is in Arabic format.

3) Then I am populating that data in Jquery dialog  which is constructed in jsp page  but that data is not in proper format

======================ajax call======================

```
$.ajax({

       url: "Login/getUserData.html",
       type: "GET",
      cache: false, 
      async: false,
   dataType:"json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success : function(data) {
     jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     if(data!=null)
         {
                            //*****************Start***************    
                            $("#post").dialog({
                                height : 500,
                                width : 550,
                                resizable: false,
                                modal : true,
                                open: function(){
                                    $('#cName').val(data.fname+" "+data.lname);     $('#cEmail').val(data.email);      
                                    $('#cNo').val(data.contact);    
                                    $('#dateL').val(data.currentDate);
                                   }
                            }); 
                             //*****************End***************    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#notLoggedInMessageDialog").dialog('open');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Error occured");
                    }}); 

      =====================LoginController.java =================
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Login/")
@Scope("request")
public class LoginController {

/*
 * method to get log-id user's data
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =    {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@ResponseBody
public String getUserData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println("================inside LoginController.getUserData()=============");
    UserModel uModel = (UserModel) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charaset=UTF-8");
    String user = null;
    if (uModel != null) {
        UserModel newUserModel = new UserModel();
        newUserModel.setuId(uModel.getuId());
        newUserModel.setContact(uModel.getContact());
        String email = new String(uModel.getEmail().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(uModel.getEmail() + "   encoded email = " + email);
        newUserModel.setEmail(uModel.getEmail());
        newUserModel.setFname(uModel.getFname());
        newUserModel.setLname(uModel.getLname());
        newUserModel.setEmailTemplate(uModel.getEmailTemplate());
        String current_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date());
        newUserModel.setCurrentDate(current_Date);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").create();
        user = gson.toJson(newUserModel);
        System.out.println("user = " + user);
    }
    return user;
}
}

====================postlisting.jsp====================
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
String direction = (String) request.getAttribute("data");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html;charaset=UTF-8");
%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
     <div>
        <fieldset  style="border: none;">
            <center>
                <legend>
                    <b><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.basicinfo"/></b>
                </legend>
                <table id="f1" style="text-align: justify;">
                    <tr>
                        <td ><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.cntName"/>:*</td>
                        <td ><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="cName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.cntEmail"/>:*</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cEmail" style="width: 100px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.cntNo"/>:*</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cNo" style="width: 100px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.dateL"/>:*</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="dateL" style="width: 100px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.dateA"/>:*</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="dateA" style="width: 100px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><"label.extruder.myProfile.newListing.rent"/>:*</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="rent" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                      </tr>
                </table>
               </center>
        </fieldset>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

can any body solve this problem??

Comment: You are expected to post complete and standalone questions here, possibly with code (rather than pictures). You should not force people to click on external links just to fetch basic info.

Answer (score 1):

use meta tag in Head block

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html";charset="utf-8" />
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed this issue by changing return type to void and
 by adding some code in controller as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Login/")
@Scope("request")
public class LoginController {

/*
 * method to get log-id user's data
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =         {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@ResponseBody
public void getUserData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
System.out.println("================inside   LoginController.getUserData()=============");
UserModel uModel = (UserModel) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
 String user = null;
if (uModel != null) {
    UserModel newUserModel = new UserModel();
    newUserModel.setuId(uModel.getuId());
    newUserModel.setContact(uModel.getContact());
    String email = new String(uModel.getEmail().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(uModel.getEmail() + "   encoded email = " + email);
    newUserModel.setEmail(uModel.getEmail());
    newUserModel.setFname(uModel.getFname());
    newUserModel.setLname(uModel.getLname());
    newUserModel.setEmailTemplate(uModel.getEmailTemplate());
    String current_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date());
    newUserModel.setCurrentDate(current_Date);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").create();
    user = gson.toJson(newUserModel);

   //new code added
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.getWriter().write(user);
}
return user;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use **filter** for encodeing in **web.xml** file

```
<filter>  
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
<init-param>  
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
</init-param>  
<init-param>  
   <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
   <param-value>true</param-value>  
</init-param>
```

`<filter-mapping>

    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>

    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>`